# glfwCreateWindow returns NULL

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I have been working on a small openGL project using C++ in Visual Studio 2015. I am using GLFW and GLEW.

After having some hardware trouble (hard disk) I reinstalled windows on my laptop. Now I try to continue on my project which was running/debugging without trouble before, but now I get an error.

glfwCreateWindow() returns NULL (even without any glfwWindowHints), and glewInit() fails also.

I thought it was because of my drivers, but I have updated drivers for both my integrated graphic cards (Intel HD 4000) and my high performance Nvidia GPU.

Using *openGL extension viewer*, I see that the integrated card support OpenGL 4.0 and the Nvidia GPU supports 4.4.

This project is rather large, so just to eliminate problem I created a simple create a triangle code based on GLFW and GLEW, but I still get error from glfwWindowCreate().

I have googled, and other than updating the drivers, I can't find other solutions. What can cause this failure?

Comment: "*I have updated drivers for both my integrated graphic cards (Intel HD 4000) and my high performance Nvidia GPU.*" Odds are good that you at one point in your old install did something to make your machine use NVIDIA's GPU for your programs. You'll need to find out what that was and do it again.

Comment: For some reason my NVIDIA control panel doesn't let me assign my Nvidia GPU to Visual Studio (the option is greyed out), while for other programs I can choose.
Anyway, both graphic processor should be able to handle openGL 4.0+

I also managed to assigned the Nvidia processor to the compiled exe file, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Set an error callback and see what it tells you.

Comment: I found my mistake. I wrote: if (!glfwInit) Instead of: if (!glfwInit())

Answer (score 6):

Did you correctly init glfw ?

```
if(!glfwInit()){
    return -1;
}
```

Then everything should be fine.

Comment: I run this and it passes:
 
        if (!glfwInit())
 {
  fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLFW\n");
 }

Answer (score 1):

Just posting my solution;
I did a stupid mistake, I had my .dll files in a different folder (with the exe files). They should be in the project folder, if I don't specify anything else in the project settings I guess.

The reason I didn't notice, was that if I removed the dll files completely, I got a dll error message, but by keeping the in the .exe folder, I just couldn't start GLFW or glew.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue where `glfwInit()` was successful but `glfwCreateWindow` was returning NULL. But I made a mistake by giving 0 for MAJOR version instead for MINOR version like below.

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 0);
```

instead

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 0);
```

Make sure you have given the version numbers properly.